# Error in running of setup file in another machine

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am created a desktop application and converted to exe format.In my current system it working properly.But the problem is when i install into another pc,installation will completed successfully but when login ,it will show the error,

*****See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
************** Exception Text **************

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
    at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)*****
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that the SQL server can't be accessed by that PC, does the client pc have access to the SQL instance.

A common mistake is using localhost when developing and when deploying not changing it to the proper network path

Comment: My connection string is this:
 **con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Drai.mdf;Integrated Security=True");**
Is there any option to change any settings of client machine???
waiting for your valuable answer

Comment: Yep the period at the front of the connection string .\\SQLEXPRESS specifies local machine, change it to the network path to the SQL server. You might also need to change the Integrated security part.

Comment: We use configuration settings so we can easily change settings when deploying a solution and don't need to make changes to the host, thus consider changing the config file and not the host

Comment: Sure sir,if you have any such code please be attach here.

Comment: Yes please see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for standard settings